# Can multiple reminders be set as default in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, reminder, lightning, thunderbird-addon

Is it possible to set Thunderbird so that when a new calendar item is added, *multiple* reminders can be created, by default? For example, the first reminder might be for two days in advance, to *prepare* for an event, and the second reminder 30 minutes before the actual calendar time.

Apparently, this has been entered as a [request in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724141), but I see no resolution, nor an add-on to do so.

Thanks for any help to let me know how to do this, or if it *cannot* be set as a default.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a default reminder for events and tasks that will always fire *n* minutes before it starts, so the second reminder still needs you to click *Custom* then *Add* to manually set the second one.

There are notifications that can be customized to fire the way you describe, since you can add as many as you want:
[image: Thunderbird on Windows in dark mode, showing the reminder defaults and notification settings. Here two notifications are created for calendar events, one alarms two days prior and the other 30 minutes before it starts.]

Might be worth a try seeing if you can set multiple reminders from this [config store](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configuring-lightning) (I can't find the mentioned Config Editor):

```
calendar.alarms.onforevents = true
calendar.alarms.eventalarmlen = 30,2880
calendar.alarms.eventalarmunit = minutes
calendar.alarms.show = true
```

[image: A screenshot of the Config Editor in Thunderbird on a Mac running OS X]*Portions of this content are ©1998–2022 by individual mozilla.org contributors. Content available under a Creative Commons license.*

Comment: Thanks, it simplifies setting the alarms, but not quite automating it, though.

Comment: No, far from, and I doubt notifications will show up on your mobile device like event reminders should. Hopefully someone can extend it with an add-on. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

1. You can open your "Tasks" tab, then right-click on your calendar that
   you usually add the events on it from left down corner, then choose
   Properties from the menu. [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2K2c.png)
2. Now, press the "Add notification" button and insert the time you
   want, then click it again to insert another reminder. [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaKuf.png)

Every time you add an event to that calendar, it will reminders you with your preferences.
But it seems this does work on events only, not tasks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1151124)